# Distance by zip code formula

Tags: mysql, math, distance

I found this formula and it works, however what i trying to do is to give ability to filter by distance from his ZIP code.

I found formula that calculates distance between two latitude and longitude coordinates.

```
(3956 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(start_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(end_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(end_lon) - RADIANS(start_lon)) + SIN(RADIANS(start_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(end_lat))))
```

I have filter on page that sends following info

```
$_POST["start_latitude"] = 34.023179;
$_POST["start_longitude"] = -118.303965;
$_POST["max_distance"] = 50;
```

If i do

```
SELECT (3956 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS({$_POST["start_latitude"]})) * COS(RADIANS(34.018626)) 
        * COS(RADIANS(-118.249978) - RADIANS({$_POST["start_longitude"]}))
         + SIN(RADIANS({$_POST["start_latitude"]})) * SIN(RADIANS(34.018626))))
```

Will output distance as number of miles 4 miles in this case.

How can i convert this formula for my goal to find places no longer than say 50 miles from coordinates entered? I know all need to be done is change of places in formula, but i am not good with school math.

```
SELECT place_name FROM places 
    WHERE place_latitude = ? AND place_longitude = ?
```

**EDIT:**

I have places table where i got 1000 records in format

```
id place_name latitude longitude
 1  xxx        432423   -43432
 2  yyy        523452   -54353
 3  zzz        553453   -53422
etc.
```

So the formula has to do something like

```
SELECT place_name FROM places 
   (CALCULATE each place distance from 
    $_POST["start_latitude"] and $_POST["start_longitude"]
    and select only ones that) < 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the distance formula into the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT place_name
FROM places
WHERE (3956 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(:start_latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(-longitude) - RADIANS(:start_longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(:start_latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(latitude))))
    < :max_distance
```

Comment: Splendid just want i needed.

Comment: On second thought this does not do anything different than formula i had. let me edit my question

Comment: It's the same formula. I thought you just wanted to know how to use it to select specific rows.

Comment: I fixed it to refer to the table columns instead of hard-coded latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

This resouce and web service usefull, check it:
http://www.codebump.com/services/PlaceLookup.asmx

```
function calc_distance($point1, $point2)
{
    $radius      = 3958;      // Earth's radius (miles)
    $deg_per_rad = 57.29578;  // Number of degrees/radian (for conversion)

    $distance = ($radius * pi() * sqrt(
                ($point1['lat'] - $point2['lat'])
                * ($point1['lat'] - $point2['lat'])
                + cos($point1['lat'] / $deg_per_rad)  // Convert these to
                * cos($point2['lat'] / $deg_per_rad)  // radians for cos()
                * ($point1['long'] - $point2['long'])
                * ($point1['long'] - $point2['long'])
        ) / 180);

    return $distance;  // Returned using the units used for $radius.
}
```

---

### **EDIT**

Check the page :
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2690/calculate-the-geographical-distance-between-two-cities-in-sql-server/

--

```
DECLARE @98001 GEOGRAPHY;
DECLARE @Patzip GEOGRAPHY;

SELECT @98001 = Coordinates  FROM         ZipCodeLKUP INNER JOIN
                      Facility ON ZipCodeLKUP.ZipCode = Facility.ZipCode
                      Where Facility.ZipCode=98001

SELECT @Patzip = Coordinates  FROM         ZipCodeLKUP INNER JOIN
                      HIDIMV_year ON ZipCodeLKUP.ZipCode = HIDIMV_year .Patzip
                      where PATZIP in ('98001', '98466','97202')

SELECT @98001.STDistance(@Patzip)/1000 AS [Distance in KM]
```

Comment: I want to have formula inside SQL request not PHP